# How can I approach mentioning my previous work experience, when I worked under a different name for 8 years?

Tags: resume

I worked for a big "mom and pops" shop for 8 years. I started when I didn't have a work permit at the time, needed work direly. Since then a few years later, I obtained my residency. Instead of talking to my boss, I quit my job and started looking for a new job.

Now I am having trouble finding a new job because I don't know how i can approach putting those 8 years Work Experience on my Resume. Since most employees would rather contact your previous employer, my previous employer had no idea i was employed under a different name?

Should I put it down on my resume and explain verbally when applying? or make some sort of note on my resume? I would like to use this experience i gained and not start off "from scratch" at a new company. Though i may not have much choice.

What can i do?

Comment: The querant may be worried about a stalker, or e associated with a panful breakup., or otherwise hesitate to expose the old name until necessary.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't even mention it unless you get asked to supply references.  If they do, you can then say something like:

> When I worked for [Employer], they knew me as [old name].  I have subsequently changed my name, which they are unaware of.  They will only know my old name, so please refer to me as that when contacting them.

**Caveat** - Be prepared to justify the reasons for changing your name as it is somewhat unusual unless you have married or divorced.  Note that there are many other valid reasons for changing your name including gender change, or even a simple dislike of your old name.  As long as you can reasonably explain it, it's unlikely to raise any red flags.

Comment: Changing names is becoming less uncommon (as is changing genders, for that matter). Some folks will be confused, but fewer than you might expect. Depending on details, delaying bringing up the issue might be the better part of valor, but this is really no different than a woman marrying and taking her husband's name;l, or changing countries and adopting a local nickname; either way the old company might need the old name, and HR ought to be able to deal with that. Jane, how do women handle the married-name issue? Via the phrasing you suggest?

Comment: @keshlam Most women simply handle it as "I subsequently changed my last name when I got married/divorced.  They will only know my old name, etc."  That's what I did when I changed my name, and it never raised any sort of issue.

Comment: Ok, so your proposed formulation in the answer is a direct parallel; it just skips explaining whether the new name is due to marriage, divorce, personal reinvention, safety or anything else -- all details the employer really doesn't need to know.

Comment: @keshlam Well, I _did_ say why, but that was me :)  If it _isn't_ because of marriage or divorce or something you can readily identify (such as a gender change or a derivation of the original name), then you may be asked about it.

Comment: And if you're asked, as you say, you can tell them. Works for me...

Comment: Just saying: In most countries, men can also change their names when getting married or divorced.

Comment: @gnasher729 Point taken :)

Comment: @keshlam In some places, I believe, such question would be prohibited, similarly to why it's prohibited to ask about the marital status. Or am I wrong?